# Looping a function over unique column id's only

Tags: python, statistics

I have a code that calculates the slope of x and y variables (the theil-sen slope) and I want to run this on a list of values based on specific column values in a csv file. My file looks like this:

`station_id      year      Sum
  210018      1917    329.946
  210018      1918    442.214
  210018      1919    562.864
  210018      1920    396.748
  210018      1921    604.266
  210019      1917    400.946
  210019      1918    442.214
  210019      1919    600.864
  210019      1920    250.748
  210019      1921    100.266`

The function I am using is:

```
def theil_sen(x,y):

    n   = len(x)
    ord = numpy.argsort(x)
    xs  = x[ord]
    ys  = y[ord]
    vec1 = numpy.zeros( (n,n) )
    for ii in range(n):
        for jj in range(n):
            vec1[ii,jj] = ys[ii]-ys[jj]
    vec2 = numpy.zeros( (n,n) )
    for ii in range(n):
        for jj in range(n):
            vec2[ii,jj] = xs[ii]-xs[jj]
    v1    = vec1[vec2>0]    
    v2    = vec2[vec2>0]     
    slope = numpy.median( v1/v2 )
    coef  = numpy.zeros( (2,1) ) 
    b_0   = numpy.median(y)-slope*numpy.median(x)
    b_1   = slope
    res   = y-b_1*x-b_0 # residuals 

    return (b_0,b_1,res)
```

I want to use `Sum` as the y value in the function, `year` as the x value and only run the function on each unique `station_id` value.  My output should be:

```
210018: -117189, 61.29
210019: 164382, -85.45
```

I am aware that scipy has a theil slope function, but it is an incorrect calculation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `numpy.unique()` to obtain the unique values in station_ids, then loop over them:

```
for id in numpy.unique(station_id):
    print id, theil_sen(year[station_id == id], Sum[station_id == id])
```

alternatively, you might want to have a look at `pandas` which has `csv` support and the `groupby` feature.

Comment: that seems to work for station 21008, but for 210019 it returns nan, nan.  For what its worth this is exactly what happens when I try to use:                       stat=df.groupby(['station_id']).apply(lambda x : theil_sen(x['Sum'], x['year']))

Comment: I copied your data from above into three arrays and it works for me (Also your pandas approach is exactly what I had in mind). Are you sure the data is read in correctly and in the form you put it here?

Comment: Hmm.  I am reading the data in as a csv file from pandas that is identical in content to what I posted.  Bare with me,  I am new to python,  what do you mean loaded in as 3 arrays?

Comment: Disregard last comment i will make each column an array and try.  Thanks for the help thus far

Comment: sorry, for being misleading. I literally copy&pasted the data:

`sid  = numpy.array([210018,210018,210018,210018,210018,210019,210019,210019,210019,210019])
year = numpy.array([1917, 1918, 1919, 1920, 1921,1917, 1918, 1919, 1920, 1921])
sum = numpy.array([329.946,442.214,562.864,396.748,604.266,400.946,442.214,600.864,250.748,100.266])

for id in np.unique(sid):
    print id, theil_sen(year[sid == id], sum[sid == id])`

Comment: btw, I think in your pandas approach you are missing `.values` to convert back to a numpy array:  
stat=df.groupby(['station_id']).apply(lambda x : theil_sen(x['Sum'].values, x['year'].values))

Comment: All I needed was add the .values and it works great.  Thank you!  The reason your original post wasn't working was I needed to load in my columns as arrays and then it was fine.